# image alignment in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML & CSS and I have a basic problem. I can not align an image in center. I have used float, scroll and many other attributes but nothing worked out.

Here is the part of CSS -

```
.slideshow-image {
    width : 500px;
    scroll : center;
}
```

Here is the part of HTML -

```
<div id = "content">
    <div class = "slideshow">
        <img src = mbuntu-1.png class = "slideshow-image" />
    </div>................
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing to try is:

```
.slideshow-image {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can check out http://howtocenterincss.com. If you're willing to use a slightly hacky solution that will almost certainly work:

```
.slideshow-image {
    position: relative; /* absolute works too */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but this solution is not working. It's not moving image to center and I do not want any other way accept the css method/attributes. I want to make site responsive otherwise there can be margin-left attribute to drag image to center.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `text-align: center` on the element that is the parent of the `img`, like so:

CSS:

```
.slideshow {
    text-align: center;
}
.slideshow-image {
    width : 500px;
    scroll : center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "content">
    <div class = "slideshow">
        <img src = mbuntu-1.png class = "slideshow-image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This should make your `img` horizontally align to the center of the parent `div`.

Comment: No it's not working. I have already tried this one. There seems to be specific attribute for image alignment.

Comment: How do you mean, it's not working? I pasted your code into a JSfiddle and added my part, after which the image was centered - the goal you are trying to achieve has been achieved. Does it result into something else for you, you mean to say? Or what's the problem exactly?